# Ruby on Rails: Is it possible to DRY up routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the nested resource "resources :comments" added to a lot of parent resources as follows (using Rails 3):

```
resources :cusines do
  resources :comments
end

resources :recipes do
  resources :comments
end

resources :chefs do
  resources :comments
end

resources :countries do
  resources :comments
end

etc., etc., etc.
```

Since I have about 10 similar ones like the above, I figure it's not very DRY. Is it possible to DRY up my routes somehow that nests the comments resource for all needed resources (that is, so I don't have to type "resources :comments" every time)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could iterate over the various things you want comments on and define the resources like:

```
[:cuisines, :countries, :recipes, :chefs].each do |r|
  resources r do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the tip Shadwell :)